# How to deactivate Adobe CS6 install on a damaged/corrupt mountain lion OS hard disk?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, repair, formatting, adobe

I have tried running the disk utility repair tool on my Mac OS HD to no avail.

So I moved on to backing as many files (Documents, iPhoto Library, Desktop Data etc...) as I could through my Windows installation on Bootcamp using MacDrive.

Although, I am ready to erase and format the HD, I am still wondering how I would re- install my CS6 suite (Desktop Application; not Creative Cloud) onto the formatted system without running into any activation/re-licensing issues.

Please note that I do have the original .dmg file (If not I could always download that from the original download portal).

However, from what I have read (http://forums.adobe.com/message/4867168), it seems like it is quite important that I deactivate and re-install on the cleaned system. 
And there is no way I can open any of these applications since I cant get the disk to boot.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Note: I do have a windows bootcamp with HD access to my Mac OS.

Comment: Are you using Creative Cloud or is it a disc install?

Comment: Its a full desktop app install; not creative cloud. I have updated the question to reflect this. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I have lost activations due to drive failure, if you read the TOS you should be allowed at least two activations. 1 for main the the other for a backup machine. As far as I can tell you are only allowed these two activations, both are used and neither is deactivated your SOL. I'd suggest calling Adobe, and plead your case, though I have not had much luck doing so in the past.

Comment: @hoss Thanks for the info. I'd have imagined adobe having a plan in place to handle such scenarios.
So essentially, If I did lose my activation due to a bad HD, Im left with a single activation and will not be able to load it on to a second computer?

Comment: you will have to read the TOS or EULA http://www.adobe.com/go/eulas and http://www.adobe.com/go/activation to know for sure, but if you are granted two activations and have used one you should be able to install one more time.

Comment: @hoss You are correct. I was told that I will be allowed 2 installs at the time of purchase. But at the end of it all, I am still bound to lose one activation. Is there no way of salvaging this? Thanks!

Comment: When I had this problem (computer replaced under warranty) they reset my activations without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://www.adobe.com/go/activation
[image: Deactivation problems]

So you might be best contacting them.

Comment: oops, link is fixed now.

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it sorted.